# How can I merge these mysql statements

Tags: mysql

I have 2 working MYSQL statements, that I would like to merge into 1 query:

from [mysql select statement with unique and maximum selects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912452/mysql-select-statement-with-unique-and-maximum-selects) I have:

```
SELECT field_a, max(dup_number) as dup FROM table1 GROUP BY field_a
```

my second query is:

```
where contacts=0 ORDER BY date LIMIT 3
```

so a group of records would look schematically like:

```
ID     FIELD A     DUP_NUMBER  CONTACTS 
1       text1        0           1        --
2       text2        0           3        --
3       text2        1           3         --
4       text2        2           3        --
5       text3        0           2        --
```

I've come up with:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1 `
where max(`DUP_NUMBER `) as dup  and `CONTACTS`=1
GROUP BY `FIELD_A`
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 3
```

When I test in PHPMyAdmin I get

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.
```

Can anyone show me how to rewrite this correctly?

Comment: can you explain more what are you trying to do?

Comment: you said two working queries . is the second working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT *, max(DUP_NUMBER) as dup FROM table1 where  CONTACTS=1 GROUP BY FIELD_A ORDER BY date LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score -2):

Problem's here:

```
where max(`DUP_NUMBER `) as dup  and `CONTACTS`=1
                         ^^^^^^
```

you can't alias things in a where clause, only in the field list, e.g.:

```
SELECT max(DUP_NUMBER) as dup
HAVING dup=???
```

is how you'd use it.