# Is it possible to rewrite this mySQL statement as a WHERE clause for redbean ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

based on [How can I merge these mysql statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928154/how-can-i-merge-these-mysql-statements?noredirect=1#comment22690941_15928154)  I have the following working sql statement:

```
SELECT *, max(DUP_NUMBER) as dup FROM table1 where  CONTACTS=1 GROUP BY FIELD_A ORDER BY date LIMIT 3
```

I am using the redbean ORM http://redbeanphp.com/finding_beans , which uses 'bean' objects to represent rows. I would like to use a specific method called findAll which requires that the assosciated sql query start with the WHERE keyword

```
$all = R::findAll('needle',' where $sql ');
```

It seems unlikely but I figured I would ask , given this constraint is there anyway to rewrite the entire query above into a WHERE SQL clause. something like:

```
" WHERE  max(DUP_NUMBER) as dup  where  CONTACTS=1 GROUP BY FIELD_A ORDER BY date LIMIT 3 "
```

THE "SELECT *" and  " from table" are taken care of by the R::findAll. If this is impossible I will simply do it another way.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the [SQL Query](http://redbeanphp.com/queries) link on the "Finding Beans" page you referenced, you will find an example of retrieving beans with custom queries at the bottom:

```
$sql = 'SELECT author.* FROM author 
        JOIN club WHERE club.id = 7 ';
    $rows = R::getAll($sql);
    $authors = R::convertToBeans('author',$rows);
```

So for your case, it might look something like:

```
$rows = R::getAll('SELECT *, max(DUP_NUMBER) as dup FROM table1 where  CONTACTS=1 GROUP BY FIELD_A ORDER BY date LIMIT 3');
$all = R::convertToBeans('needle', $rows);
```

assuming `'needle'` is your bean type.